# If statement comparing variable value extracted from beautifulsoup

Tags: python, if-statement, unicode, beautifulsoup

I am stuck after several iterations and cannot figure out what I am getting wrong here but I assume that it has sth to do with the variable type I am looking at.

I am parsing some html from a site:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
url = 'XXX'

page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
soup.prettify()

tag = soup.find("div", { "class" : "no-results--header" })
no_product = tag.text
```

When I assess the value for no_product I find:

```
print no_product
#No Product
print type(no_product)
#<type 'unicode'>
```

When I now try to evaluate an if statement this does not work out:

```
if no_product == 'No Product':
  print 'Success'
else:
  print 'Failure'
```

This if clause always returns 'Failure'. I have tried to encode the no_product variable as string with

```
no_product = no_product.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Still the if statement will return 'Failure'.

I am running Python 2.7.10.

Comment: What does `print repr(no_product)` output?

Comment: u'\nNo Product\n'

Comment: as Tom said, just add the u.  I am not as sure as he is that you need the newlines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, `print repr(no_product)` outputs `u'\nNo Product\n'`.  This means that the value of `no_product` includes both a leading and trailing newline.

In order for the comparison to succeed, you need to either strip the newlines:

```
if no_product.strip('\n') == 'No Product':
```

or change the string you're testing for:

```
if no_product == '\nNo Product\n':
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say the correct 'if' statement should be:

```
if no_product == u'No Product':
```

the `u` tells Python it is a unicode string.

I would suggest, however, that instead of a straight equality, you leverage the `in` keyword:

```
if 'No Product' in no_product:
```

This would assume that no_product would not be expected to contain the phrase "no Product" unless the results were what you expected above.  I also like the `in` construct because it eliminates the possibility of hidden whitespace creating a non-match.